# Equivalent definitions of cutoff time for Markov chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

The cutoff phenomenon for Markov chains is defined as follows

> Suppose for a sequence of Markov Chains indexed by $n = 1, 2, \cdots$, the mixing time for the $n$-th chain at kevel $\epsilon$ is denoted by $t_{mix}^{n}(\epsilon)$. The sequence of chains has a $\textbf{cutoff}$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ , 
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle\frac{t_{mix}^{n}(\epsilon)}{t_{mix}^{n}(1 - \epsilon)} = 1$$

I came across a equivalent definition which says that the sequence has a cutoff if the total variation distance from the stationary distribution $d_n(t)$ satisfies
$$d_n((1-\epsilon)t_{mix}^n(1/2)) \to 1 \\d_n((1+\epsilon)t_{mix}^n(1/2)) \to 0
$$
How are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: a) Presumably $t_{\mathrm{mix}}^n(\varepsilon) = \inf\{t : d_n(t) \le \varepsilon\}?$ You should add that to the Q. b) What did you try and where are you stuck? c) As a hint, presumably you understand the idea of the cutoff - that for large $n$, $d_n(t)$ tends to stay nearly flat and near $1$ for a long time, then quickly dip to near 0 and then stay pretty flat again. Given this, sketch a plot of $d_n(t)$ for large $n$, and mark out the times and the $d_n$s being indicated in the two definitions, and try to figure out what they're saying about the

Comment: (contd) behaviour of the points/intervals you marked in the plots as $n$ blows up (and why this aligns with your intuitions about cutoff). This should suggest an argument for equivalence. If you don't understand what the phenomenon being captured is, I'd suggest reading about that before crunching the definitions. d) You might need the following trivial observation to fomally make the argument: if $\limsup_n f(n) \le 1 + O(\varepsilon)$ for all $\varepsilon > 0,$ then $\limsup_n f(n) \le 1.$ (why?).

Comment: I see. The lecture I was watching seemed to suggest that the equivalence is very trivial by some scaling of time which I don't really see

Comment: Also, is there something special about $t_{mix}^n(1/2)$ or will it be true for any  $t_{mix}^n(r)$ for any $0<r<1$?

Comment: It _is_ kind of trivial, once you draw the plot. To formally show it you'll have to chuck in some delta, because the epsilons in the two different equations are doing different things (and this is why i was talking about the limit at the end). And yes, nothing is special about 1/2 per se, because in the limit the behaviour of the distance from the stationary law is a step at the scale of the mixing time.